# css position issue within Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've created a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/daFalk/dx3xLgLq/2/
its all about the css styles

```
div.ding-wrap {
    position: absolute;
}
```

As you can see there is an image well positioned if you open it with chrome or any other normal browser.

But if I open it with internet Explorer the image is gone! I need to change the positioning of ding-wrap to relative.

i would do so, but then my animations (not there) does not work very well. So I need the positioning absolute. How can I teach IE to take me serious?

Thanks, Falk

Comment: I don't figure out what's wrong with your CSS code, there are so many CSS code. And you try to use `display: table` and `position: absolute` to center the div, I support you to look the demo [Absolute center](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt) it will give you more inspiration. Back to the question, I support you to remove some CSS and see if it normal, and locate the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

jiangshui gave a push in the right direction. I stopped centering via table and table-cell and used

```
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
```

for centering. Sadly, always if I googled vertical centering, everywhere I read only about the first method because the auto-margin shouldnt work. And I never tried. So thanks a lot to jiangshui!

Here the updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/daFalk/dx3xLgLq/5/

Comment: Actually, use table cell is a good way to make thing center, I do some demo before [http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/c3ujr/](http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/c3ujr/) and [http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/8v6Wq/](http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/8v6Wq/)( if you use float for the li ). Hope it will help you. :)